# How to fix 'Unable to Obtain Authentication Token' in Active Directory Authentication to Azure Analysis Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, ssms, azure-analysis-services

I am simply trying to follow the steps [here](https://www.sanjaybhagia.com/2018/11/12/accessing-azure-analysis-services-models-using-net-core/) so that I can query an Azure Analysis Services model from C#. But in SQL Server Management Studio I fail to connect to the server when using "Active Directory - Password" authentication, getting error message "Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided..."

I tried using the username displayed in Analysis Services Admins that looks like this: **john.doe_outlook.com#EXT#@johndoeoutlook.onmicrosoft.com** 
and the outlook e-mail address associated with the Azure account which is of this form **john.doe@outlook.com**.

The password I used is also my Microsoft account password. From researching, it is never made clear to me at all what password I should be typing in, where do I get it from? Or what exactly do I need to do here so that I can successfully connect?

Both usernames I tried result in this message:

**Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided. If your Active Directory tenant administrator has configured Multi-Factor Authentication or if your account is a Microsoft Account, please remove the user name and password from the connection string, and then retry. You should then be prompted to enter your credentials. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)**

If I enter **john.doe_outlook.com#EXT#@johndoeoutlook.onmicrosoft.com** as the username I get these messages:

**user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)**

**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (System)**

and if I enter **john.doe@outlook.com** as the username I get these messages:

**Sequence contains no elements (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new a app registration and selected 
'Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)'
instead of
'Accounts in this organizational directory only (Default Directory)'.
When I connect to the server in SSMS, I select Active Directory with MFA support instead of Active Directory-Password, and I enter john.doe@outlook.com. And it connects.

Comment: I have a similar issue but it's using Power BI Desktop to connect back to Power BI SSAS via OleDb.Query function. If I choose Windows Authentication, the above issue happen if there are many request sent in a short period of time. However, if I select database connection without authentication then it will prompt for MFA and work perfectly.